# Scala Play - Binding multiple checkboxes

Tags: forms, scala, checkbox, playframework, form-helpers

I am building a scala play 2.3.x web application and I have a form where I have a question with multiple possible answers (checkboxes, to allow user to choose several answers).

The play documentation provides an example to include one checkbox using

```
@checkbox(field = myForm("done"))
```

But in my case I have several questions, each with multiple possible answers.

Looking at the documentation, there is a similar situation for radio buttons using

```
@inputRadioGroup(
   contactForm("gender"),
    options = Seq("M"->"Male","F"->"Female"),
    '_label -> "Gender",
    '_error -> contactForm("gender").error.map(_.withMessage("select gender")))
```

Why don't we have a @checkboxGroup(...) to handle this case?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

see this document:[inputCheckboxGroup](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputCheckboxGroup$)

```
@inputCheckboxGroup(
contactForm("hobbies"),
options = Seq("S" -> "Surfing", "R" -> "Running", "B" -> "Biking","P" -> "Paddling"),
'_label -> "Hobbies",
'_error -> contactForm("hobbies").error.map(_.withMessage("select one or more hobbies")))
```